# Zed Attack Proxy Dynamic Certificate Won't Import To Firefox

Tags: firefox, zap

The last time I did a scan (on OWASP 2.4.0 using Firefox version of the same timeframe), I was easily able to generate the dynamic ssl cert, save it (as a cer) and import it to Firefox. Now, with ZAP 2.7.0 and Firefox 51.0.1 it doesn't work.

Now, Firefox is griping about "This personal certificate can’t be installed because you do not own the corresponding private key which was created when the certificate was requested." I am no ZAP, or certificate, expert, but shouldn't this work? Chrome and IE don't complain about the cert, but they do silently fail to import it. Which means I can't do the scans I needed to get done... By tomorrow...

What am I missing?

Thanks!
Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are adding the certificate in the wrong Firefox tab. You need to add it in the 'Authorities tab' and check the 'Trust this CA to identify web sites.' box.

BTW if you (or anyone else) have urgent queries about ZAP then I'd recommend either using the ZAP User Group (https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users, also linked off the ZAP 'Online' menu) or ask on irc - for details of that see https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy#-owasp-zap

Comment: Ahhhh THANKS! Going to chalk this one up to a 16 hour work day doing vulnerability scans. :)